# Active admin change headers for the csv as well as add text to the output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Hi there i want to be able to change what the headers are for the output of the csv. So instead of :name = "name" i would like to change it to for example "client name". Without renaming the variable. How can i do this.

Example being like.

```
column "client name", :name
```

-

Additionally i would like to add cf to the output of the id so it would show for example "3 cf" rather than 3. Something like this but working.

```
    column(:id) + "CF"
```

-
Full code. For Orders.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  scope :not_completed_orders
  menu priority: 3
  batch_action :manifest do |ids|
    redirect_to "/admin/orders.csv?q[id_in][]=" + ids.join("&q[id_in][]=")
  end

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    column :user
    column :name
    column :delivery_name
    column :complete
    column :delivery_address1
    column :service
    column :insurance
    actions
  end

  csv do
    column :created_at
    column :name
    column :delivery_name
    column(:id)
  end

  permit_params do
    permitted = [:email ,:country ,:city ,:postcode, :address_line_2, :address_line_1 ,:user_id, :name, :delivery_name, :company_name, :delivery_address1, :delivery_address2, :delivery_address3, :delivery_city, :delivery_postcode, :delivery_country, :phone, :package_contents, :description_content, :restricted_items, :terms_conditions, :insurance, :contents_value, :cf_reference, :reference_number, :complete]
    permitted
  end
end
# completed_at
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your csv block you can define your own custom header like this:

```
column "client name" do |order|
  order.name
end
```

Same for the custom values:

```
column "ID" do |user|
  "#{user.id} CF" 
end
```

Or if you prefer single line you can change the code above to be something like this:

```
column("client name"){ |order| order.name }
```

Similar code applies to custom values.

Comment: One small clarification - the column names get humanized. So if you want to preserve case, such as an all caps column header, then use something like column("CLIENT NAME", humanize_name: false){ |order| order.name }

Answer (score 4):

solved with column parameter `humanize_name: false`

```
csv force_quotes: true do
    column :a_b_c_d, humanize_name: false
end
```